# json_decode can't display array

Tags: php, arrays, json

OK I have looked at a few examples and I can't seem to display the array or an element. It keeps coming back as null-. I have the following JSON (from mapquest)

```
renderGeocode({
    results: [
        {
            locations: [
                {
                    latLng: {
                        lng: -90.1978,
                        lat: 38.627201
                    },
                    adminArea4: "Saint Louis City",
                    adminArea5Type: "City",
                    adminArea4Type: "County",
                    adminArea5: "Saint Louis",
                    street: "",
                    adminArea1: "US",
                    adminArea3: "MO",
                    type: "s",
                    displayLatLng: {
                        lng: -90.1978,
                        lat: 38.627201
                    },
                    linkId: 0,
                    postalCode: "",
                    sideOfStreet: "N",
                    dragPoint: false,
                    adminArea1Type: "Country",
                    geocodeQuality: "CITY",
                    geocodeQualityCode: "A5XAX",
                    mapUrl: "http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=123456789&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,38.627201,-90.1978,0,0|&center=38.627201,-90.1978&zoom=12&rand=1390479880",
                    adminArea3Type: "State"
                }
            ],
            providedLocation: {
                location: "SAint Louis,mo"
            }
        }
    ],
    options: {
        ignoreLatLngInput: false,
        maxResults: -1,
        thumbMaps: true
    },
    info: {
        copyright: {
            text: "© 2013 MapQuest, Inc.",
            imageUrl: "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
            imageAltText: "© 2013 MapQuest, Inc."
        },
        statuscode: 0,
        messages: [

        ]
    }
})
```

I have attempted to add it to an array like so

```
$array =json_decode($data, true);
```

However no matter how I try to print or check the contents it all comes back as null I really am just trying to print out the lat lng and adminArea5.
Any help would be great.

Here is the full code

```
<?php
$where = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'where', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$source = "getLat";
if ($source =="getLat")
{
    ob_start();
    $getsource = array('location' =>$where,
            'type'=>$getWhat,
            'callback'=>'ResultSet'
    );
    $url = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=123456789" . http_build_query($getsource, '', "&");
//print_r($url);
    $data_mapquest = file_get_contents($url);
    $array = json_decode($data_mapquest, true);
    ob_end_flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON...

Comment: That's not JSON. It's a Javascript expression. Apart from the function call wrapping, keys are unquoted. Which is why a plain `json_decode` won't work here.

Comment: Ok - any suggestions -- I am a bit of a newbie here but any guidence would be great

Comment: Please add proper tabbing to your code.

Comment: OK - I guess I can trim off the renderGeocode

Comment: lol thanks Mario I think we both typed that in same time-

Comment: Where is that coming from? Can you get *real* JSON instead?

Comment: I do pass the inFormat param as JSON per the doc

Comment: Show us code how exactly you get this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the `'callback' => 'ResultSet'` parameter, that makes the response a [*JSONP*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response.

Comment: Thanks -- I knew it had to be something simple --